# Camouflaged sea creatures

Tags: wordplay

Can you guess the sea creatures hidden behind the following clues?

> 1. Arctic current liner + Day light screen + Gold star cat
> 2. Pyramid wall depression + Chocolate house wine + Blue whale pool
> 3. Office mail car + Royal bean bracelet + Lion cake oil
> 4. Baby neck water + Piercing dive job + Common striped spinner
> 5. Camel road speed + Horse massage alley + White killer shark

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following on from Thomas Blue's answer, some others

1

> OCEAN (Arctic/current/liner) + SUN (Day/light/screen) + (Gold/star/cat) FISH

3

> BOX (Office/mail/car) + JELLY (Royal/bean/bracelet) + FISH (Lion/cake/oil)

5

> (Camel/road/speed) HUMP + BACK (Horse/massage/alley) + (White/killer/shark) WHALE

Answer (score 16):

Just to spoil everything:

> Three words form a clue in a way that a common word may finish them.

Seen in:

(2)

> GREAT(Pyramid/wall/depression) + WHITE(Chocolate/house/wine) + (Blue/whale/pool)SHARK = Great white shark.

Now the pros will find the rest faster than me here.

Answer (score 12):

Think this is the last one unanswered one.

4

> Bottle (Baby neck water) + Nose (Piercing dive job) + Dolphin (Common striped spinner)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the answers given by Thomas, hexomino and Rappaport, the answers are

1

> **Ocean** (Arctic/current/liner) + **Sun** (Day/light/screen) + (Gold/star/cat) **Fish**

2

> **Great**(Pyramid/wall/depression) + **White**(Chocolate/house/wine) + (Blue/whale/pool)**Shark**

3

> **Box** (Office/mail/car) + **Jelly** (Royal/bean/bracelet) + **Fish** (Lion/cake/oil)

4

> **Bottle** (Baby neck water) + **Nose** (Piercing dive job) + **Dolphin** (Common striped spinner)

5

> **Hump** (Camel/road/speed) + **Back** (Horse/massage/alley) + (White/killer/shark) **Whale**

Comment: It just felt too messy to see all the solutions separated in different answers so I simply collected them together. If this isn't allowed then I will gladly delete this :)

Comment: Regarding 1., you have a Rot13(tbyqsvfu, fgnesvfu)... and then a Rot13(pngsvfu)? What the — ? Is that an animal?? Oddly sounds familiar... :P

Comment: @user477343 indeed. Search rot13(zbyn zbyn), it indeed exists.

Comment: rot13(fb qbrf n pngsvfu ohg vg qbrf abg ybbx yvxr n png gubhtu )

Comment: After researching, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catfish:_The_TV_Show) does not look like a Rot13(pngsvfu) either :D

Comment: Oh dear lord XD , look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catfish

Comment: I know, right? Just looked up on the *actual* one now, hahahah :P